# Casting double to int: how it really works?

Tags: c++, casting

Let's look at this program:

```
#include <iostream>

...

int main()
{
    double koza = ( 1+2, 54 + 6, foo(), bar(), (double) 8/9 );
    std::cout << koza << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be 8/9, which is `0.888889`. If I had used `static_cast<double> (8/9)` or `double(8/9)` instead, then 8/9 would be calculated firstly, which would be interpreted as `integer` (so 8/9 equals 0), then I would have casting it on `double`, which would give me `0` as an output.

But how exactly `(double) 8/9` works? Does it cast both `8` and `9` on double and then calculate that? Or it consider all that is after `(double)` as a `double` instead default `int`? Or in other way?

In classes, when we were in such a situation, wrote number as floating point numbers by adding `.0` to integer, for example :

`double x = 8.0`.

But how will it would work here? Or I should ask: how exactly this works? Is there any difference between these three expressions below?

a) `double x = 8.0 / 9;`

b) `double x = 8 / 9.0;`

c) `double x = 8.0 / 9.0;`

Comment: No, there is no difference between a, b and c! double in denominator or numerator will give you double!

Comment: Are the `foo` and `bar` methods relevant here?

Comment: It casts the `8` to a `double`, then tries to do the division, realising it must now also cast the `9` to a `double`.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen No, they are not and the question would be improved if they were stripped out.   **Kusavil:** It looks like you are trying to understand the general casting behavior of c++ by experimentation. I'm afraid that in general, it is dangerous to take the results of such experiments seriously because they may vary from compiler to compiler and worse may be technically undefined. Relying on things you learn this way can cause trouble down the road. The best bet is to use a high quality reference (or learn to read the standard).

Comment: Thank you :) @BrianRasmussen: I edited the question and deleted theirs' declarations, I hope it's more clear now. @dmckee, thank you for advice, are there some good methods you could recommend me instead using `(double) expression`, which don't really differ in different compilers ?

Comment: The templated casts (`static_cast<>` are more tightly defined than the casts inherited from c), but that advice was meant as a very general warning about assuming that the behavior of any particular compiler is reliable guide to general behavior for c or c++. Both standards leave a lot of stuff "implementation defined" or "undefined". The former allows variation from compiler to compiler. The latter allows nasal demons.

Answer (score 4):

`(double)8/9` is `((double)8)/9` - the `(double)` binds tightly.

When you operate on a `double` and an `int` with `/` the `int` is implicitly converted to a `double`.

The same is true of (most? all?) other binary operators that apply.